# Differences in adding classes to nodes and paragraphs

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to add some classes to a certain content type.

In `mytheme_preprocess_node_contentype()` I'm able to use `$variables['attributes']->addClass('myclass')`

However, in `mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs__my_paragraph()` using `$variables['attributes']->addClass('myclass')` throws an error as `$variables['attributes']` is an array.

> Error: Call to a member function addClass() on array in ...

Why are these two different?

Is okay to use `addClass()` in the node instance and just use `$variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass'` in the paragraph instance?

Comment: You usually see only the array syntax in preprocess hooks because you don't know whether the attributes are an object without checking it. The object also accepts the array syntax, so this always works.